# Update a column matching criteria in TAB seperated line using bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, tabs

I have a TAB separated txt file looking like this;

```
Serving Sector  Target Sector   HO Attempts HO Successful Attempts
1002080 1002081 8   8
1002080 1002084 0   0
1002080 1002974 2   2
1002080 2104-2975   5   5
1002080 1002976 2   2
1002080 1012237 10  10
1002080 1012281 0   0
```

In some situations the Target Sector(column 2) might be on this format 2104-2975( ABCD-YYYY).
In those cases I wish to update this string of column 2 to the correct format  (BC0YYYY = 1002975)

This is what I have written so far;

```
while read -r line;
do
        if echo $line | grep -E '([0-9])-([0-9])' # If line matches criteria
        then
                string=`echo "$line" | awk -F '\t' '{{print $2}}'`   #fetch column 2
                LAC=${string%-*}   #LAC= ABCD
                CI=${string##*-}   #CI = YYYY
                if [ ${#CI} -lt 5 ]; then CI="0"$CI;  #IF stringlength of CI is less than 5, add 0 
                fi
                LAC2=`echo $LAC | cut -c2-3` #LAC2 = BC
                GERANCELL=$LAC2$CI

        fi
done < input.txt
```

Anyone know how to update the 2nd column of the line with the new value $GERANCELL?

Comment: I don't understand why you invoke for each line an awk child process. It would be much more performant and easier to maintain, if you remove the `while` loop and instead process the whole file from within awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
    perl -lane'BEGIN{$"="\t"}if($F[1]=~/-/){($a,$b)=(split/-/,$F[1]);$F[1]=sprintf "%02d%05d",substr($a,1,2),$b;print "@F"}else{print "@F"}' file 
    erving  Sector  Target  Sector  HO  Attempts    HO  Successful  Attempts
    1002080 1002081 8   8
    1002080 1002084 0   0
    1002080 1002974 2   2
    1002080 1002975 5   5
    1002080 1002976 2   2
    1002080 1012237 10  10
    1002080 1012281 0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward `sed` solution could be:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\([0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\10\2/' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This seems like a more elegant solution, but I struggle a bit understanding what happeneing here. Running this sed I see the following changes:
```

12521-9300 become 15209300. Desired output would be 25**0**9300 and
12521-19287 become 152019287. Desired output should be 2519287

```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

- Set the field and output field separator to a tab
- Match 4 or more digits with a hyphen in between in field 2
- If there is a match, split on a hyphen
- From the first part, take the second and third character
- From the second part, prepend a `0` if the length is smaller than 5
- Set the result to field 2 (or print the values of all 4 columns immediately)
- `}1` evaluates to true, printing the whole line

Example

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
match($2, /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+$/) {
  split($2, a, "-")  
  $2 = substr(a[1],2,2) (length(a[2]) < 5 ? "0" : "") a[2]
}1
' input_file.txt | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Formatted output with column -t

```
Serving Sector  Target Sector  HO Attempts  HO Successful Attempts
1002080         1002081        8            8
1002080         1002084        0            0
1002080         1002974        2            2
1002080         1002975        5            5
1002080         1002976        2            2
1002080         1012237        10           10
1002080         1012281        0            0
1002080         2509300        0            0
1002080         2519287        0            0
```

If supported, you can shorten the pattern in the match function to `/^[0-9]{4,}-[0-9]{4,}$/`